# Download a youtube video in node js using ytdl

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, node-modules

When I download a video in HD format there is only coming video but no audio
only downloading 360p with audio other audio bitrate is null how can i bind audio in all format

```
                for(let i=0;i<data.formats.length;i++){
                    if(data.formats[i].container != "mp4"){
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    html += `
                        <option value="${data.formats[i].itag}">
                            ${data.formats[i].container} - ${data.formats[i].qualityLabel}
                        </option>
                    `;
```

downloaded from here https://github.com/imgitto/Youtube-Video-Downloader-App

can I download a video in all format with audio
[this is browser responce but showing null bredth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjEcD.png)

This project is https://download.xn--p1b1a4ab6ac4etebb0m.live/